# Unable to insert into my database table

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I am trying to insert textbox value into the database. But I was prompted with this error of "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'table' " 
There is error with the "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();" What is wrong with my codes?

Below is my code:

```
string query;
string str = "Data Source=blank blank blank;Initial Catalog=test;User ID=hello;Password=password";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
con.Open();
query = "INSERT INTO table dbo.url_map Values ('" + tbLongURL.Text + "')";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You should use parameters to pass values to your SqlCommand http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the correct syntax is

```
query = "INSERT INTO dbo.url_map Values ('" + tbLongURL.Text + "')";
```

Basically you added the word "table" into the query which is not SQL syntax. It is

`INSERT INTO tablename`

Answer (score 3):

You are not escaping the text, which can not only break your SQL query but makes you vulnerable to SQL injection if the input is not sanitized. What you SHOULD do:

```
string query;
string str = "Data Source=blank blank blank;Initial Catalog=test;User ID=hello;Password=password";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
con.Open();
query = "INSERT INTO dbo.url_map Values (@Url)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Url", tbLongURL.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: the error now is not with the table but the url_map now. What is wrong with my query?

Comment: I didn't catch it at first, but `INSERT INTO table dbo.url_map` should be `INSERT INTO dbo.url_map`

Answer (score 2):

In the **dbo.url_map** table have just a column? if this table have another columns, you can try this query

```
INSERT INTO dbo.url_map(login) VALUES('" + tbLogonURL.Text + "')";
```

Because when you no specify what column date you are inserting, your DB will try take date for all column of table, if you have column **id, logon and pass**, it will can not take date for id and pass, and this can cause error for your insert.